# filter data when multiple keywords matches regardless of the order in which it appears in the text

Tags: google-sheets, filter, keyword

I'm using the **filter formula** to get data from another tab (*products*).
I type some keywords in *C2* and I want the filter formula to return me the data when it matches with the 'product description'.

Now I'm using this condition: `SEARCH(C2; products!D2:D)` [my sheets is in Portuguese format ';']

It is working but not as desired. I want a filter formula to get the rows that contain all of the words entered in C2, regardless of the order in which they appear in the text.

Here is a sheet sample. I can't share the one I'm using:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F8Gg1rG9smjW25bmjwXP7wADFvnuyrse9aPM1iQfxsA/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to use SEARCH() and SPLIT() and I also tried SEARCH() and MATCH(). I just can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The question does not specify how the keywords in `C2` are separated. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75401788/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with sample contents of `C2`, and another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results from those parameters.

Comment: Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find rows where the product name contains *all* of the keywords, try this formula, based on rockinfreakshow's answer:

```
=lambda( 
  productNames, data, keyWords, 
  filter( 
    data, 
    counta(keyWords) 
    = 
    byrow( 
      makearray( 
        rows(productNames), counta(keyWords), 
        lambda( 
          rowIndex, columnIndex, 
          iferror( 
            sign( 
              search( 
                index(keyWords, 0, columnIndex), 
                index(productNames, rowIndex) 
              ) 
            ) 
          ) 
        )
      ), 
      lambda(numMatches, sum(numMatches)) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  A3:A, A3:B, split(E2, ", ", true, true) 
)
```

To find rows where the product name contains *any* of the keywords, try `filter()` with `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  A3:B, 
  regexmatch( 
    to_text(A3:A), 
    "(?i)" & regexreplace(to_text(E2), "[, ]+", "|") 
  ) 
)
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: It is working, but not as I expected. It is getting the data using OR. I'd like to get the data when all the words matches regardless of the order in which it appears in the text.
e.g.: 
C2 = 'apple 32' -> 
return = '32gb apple'; 'apple ipad pro 32'... 
do not return = 'Samsung 32'; 'apple TV'
THANKS

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the relevant detail there. Show tables of sample data, sample keywords and desired results.

Comment: Done, thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this out:

```
=LAMBDA(x;FILTER(x;BYROW(LAMBDA(z;MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x);COUNTA(z);LAMBDA(r;c;IF(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(x;r);"(?i)"&INDEX(z;;c)&"");1;))))(SPLIT(C2;" "));LAMBDA(y;SUM(y)))=COUNTA(SPLIT(C2;" "))))(Products!D2:D)
```

Comment: try this in your sample sheet: `=LAMBDA(x,FILTER(x,BYROW(LAMBDA(z,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(INDEX(x,,1)),COUNTA(z),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(INDEX(x,,1),r),"(?i)"&INDEX(z,,c)&""),1,))))(SPLIT(E2," ")),LAMBDA(y,SUM(y)))=COUNTA(SPLIT(E2," "))))(A:B)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm guessing your values are separated by commas. If not change it in Split

```
=FILTER(products!D2:D;BYROW(Products!D2:D;LAMBDA(each;INDEX(PRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH(TRIM(SPLIT(C2;",";1;1);each);0))))))
```

Comment: I will try when I get home. I thought it would be simple. I was trying using something like =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SEARCH(split(D2;" ");A2:A11);0)) but I just can't get the result within the FILTER. Thanks